# Reaction of sulphuric acid with ammonium hydrogen phosphate

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

How will the reaction of $\ce{H2SO4}$ with ($\ce{NH4)2HPO4}$ [diammonium phosphate, commonly used DAP fertiliser in agriculture] proceed? Will phosphoric acid be produced, or a complex phosphate-sulphate salt would be the result?

Comment: Convenient reference for text/formula formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)  // [For more:  Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  // Not to be applied in CH SE titles.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the molar ratio,

$$\ce{HPO4^2- ->[H+]H2PO4- ->[H+]H3PO4}.$$

Also remember there are no $\ce{H2SO4}$ nor $\ce{(NH4)2HPO4}$ in water solution, but $\ce{,}$ $\ce{HSO4-(aq)}$, $\ce{SO4^2-(aq)}$ , $\ce{NH4+(aq)}$ , $\ce{HPO4^2-(aq)}$,  $\ce{H2PO4^-(aq)}$ and $\ce{H3PO4(aq)}$, depending on the ratio and $\mathrm{pH}$.

For direct reaction without water, then

$$\ce{2 H2SO4 + (NH4)2HPO4 -> 2 NH4HSO4 + H3PO4},$$

with some $\ce{(NH4)2SO4}$ too.

Comment: Thank you, that’s very helpful :). From your explanation, I conclude that if the objective is to get P04 3- (soluble form of phosphate ion in acidic PH for the crop) from DAP, then a higher concentration of H2S04 should be used than an equal moles of both, and the reaction should be carried out in water.

Comment: PO4^3- is present only at very alkalic solutions. (pK_a3= 12.37)